# unable to convert svg to png using "Sharp" package getting issue in node EXE

Tags: javascript, node.js, executable, sharp, esbuild

I'm using esbuild to bundle my node application into single cJS file - https://esbuild.github.io/getting-started/#build-scripts

After that i create .exe with help of nodejs - https://nodejs.org/api/single-executable-applications.html

Into my node application i'm converting svg data into png buffer for that i'm using Sharp, and it working fine when running application locally form code

while running from executable it is throwing canvas error